# isomorphism in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

Consider  the tex:

```
\xymatrix{
    M \ar[r]^{f}\ar[d]_{h} & N \ar@{-->}[dl]^{g} \\
     P}
```

If `f` is isomorphism, not identity. How  to change the tex?
If I replace `\ar[r]^{f}` by `\ar@{\cong }[r]^{f}`, this can't  work.  How to  get  isomorphism?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way would be to add `\cong` under the arrow:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
    M \ar[r]^{f}_{\cong} \ar[d]_{h} & N \ar@{-->}[dl]^{g} \\
     P}

\end{document}
```

The `\ar@...` syntax tries to change the arrow type, but there is not really a standard arrow symbol for isomorphism.